# Array sorted into descending order

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86, irvine32

I am having trouble with sorting my array into descending order with user inputs. I can't seem to move my biggest elements into the first element of the array. This is for a CS assignment with specifc requirements that I have to follow. Basically, the code is supposed to take 40 unsigned DWORD integers, print out the inputs in an array, sort the array in descending order, then print out the array again.

Here is my code atm:

```
Title Assignment 7

COMMENT !
*****************
date: November 21, 2021

; This program takes up to 40 unsigned dword integers, puts each user input into 1 array. The array gets printed out and the array is sorted in descending order, then printed in descending order. 

*****************
!

include irvine32.inc
; ===============================================
.data
  
  ; Fill your data here
  
  msg1 byte "Enter up to 40 unsigned dword integers. To end the array, enter 0.", 0
  msg2 byte "After each element press enter: ", 0
  msg3 byte "Initial array:", 0
  msg4 byte "Array sorted in descending order:", 0
  arr1 DWORD 40 DUP (?)
  arr_length DWORD ?

;=================================================
.code
main proc

  
    
    ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE 
    ; YOU NEED TO CALL ENTER_ELEM, SORT_ARR AND PRINT_ARR PROCEDURES
    ; 
    
   mov edx, offset msg1
   call writeString
   call crlf
   mov edx, offset msg2
   call writeString
   call ReadDec
   mov esi, offset arr1
   
   sub esp, 4
   push esi
   call enter_elem

   pop arr_length                       ; saves array length
   
   call crlf
   mov edx, offset msg3
   call writeString
   mov esi, offset arr1
   
   call crlf
   sub esp, 4
   push esi
   push arr_length
   call print_arr

   call crlf
   mov edx, offset msg4
   call writeString
   mov esi, offset arr1
   sub esp, 4
   push esi
   push arr_length
   call sort_arr

   call crlf

   mov esi, offset arr1
   sub esp, 4
   push esi
   push arr_length
   call print_arr


   exit
main endp

; ================================================
; int enter_elem(arr_addr)
;
; Input:
;   ARR_ADDRESS THROUGH THE STACK
; Output:
;   ARR_LENGTH THROUGH THE STACK
; Operation:
;   Fill the array and count the number of elements
;
enter_elem proc
    
    ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE

   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov esi, [ebp + 8]               ; array address
   xor ebx, ebx                     ; counter for num of elements in the array
   top: cmp eax, 0
        je next
        mov [esi], eax
        add esi, type arr1
        call ReadDec
        inc ebx
        cmp ebx, 40
        je next
        jmp top
    
   next:
        
        mov [ebp + 12], ebx
        pop ebp
        ret 4

    

enter_elem endp

; ================================================
; void print_arr(arr_addr,arr_len)
;
; Input:
;   ?
; Output:
;   ?
; Operation:
;  print out the array
;

print_arr proc

  ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE
   
   
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
   mov esi, [ebp + 12]
   
   L1:
   mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteDec
    mov al, " "
    call WriteChar
    add esi, type arr1
    Loop L1

  pop ebp
  ret 8

print_arr endp

; ================================================
; void sort_arr(arr_addr,arr_len)
;
; Input:
;   ?
; Output:
;   ?
; Operation:
;   sort the array
;

sort_arr proc

   ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE
   ; YOU NEED TO CALL COMPARE_AND_SWAP PROCEDURE 
   
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
   mov esi, [ebp + 12]
   L2:
        mov edi, esi
        add edi, type arr1
        push esi
        push edi
        call compare_and_swap
        ;add esi, type arr1
        Loop L2

    pop ebp
    ret 8



sort_arr endp

; ===============================================
; void compare_and_swap(x_addr,y_addr)
;
; Input:
;   ?
; Output:
;   ?
; Operation:
;  compare and call SWAP ONLY IF Y < X 
;

compare_and_swap proc

   ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE
   ; YOU NEED TO CALL SWAP PROCEDURE 

   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov esi, [ebp + 8]
   mov edi, [ebp + 12]
   mov edx, [edi]
   mov ebx, [esi]
   cmp edx, ebx
   jae skipSwap
   push edx
   push ebx
   call swap

   skipSwap:
   pop ebp
   ret 8

compare_and_swap endp

; =================================================
; void swap(x_addr,y_addr)
;
; Input:
;   ?
; Output:
;   ?
; Operation:
;  swap the two inputs
;

swap proc

   ; FILL YOUR CODE HERE

   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp
   mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
   mov edx, [ebp + 12]
   mov [esi], edx
   mov [edi], ebx
   pop ebp
   ret 8



swap endp

end main
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  The approach is to single step until something goes wrong!  Watch all the state changes made (e.g. to registers or memory) and watch the control flow changes (loops, etc..).  Verify every single operation.  Try it with a very small input, maybe just 2 numbers to sort and see if it swaps them or even reads them properly.  Once working for that it will probably do more.  Also useful is to verify the algorithm you started with by running the C version of it (usually do that before translating to assembly).  Knowing the algorithm works, leaves only translation errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the `stdcall` calling convention, the callee cleans the stack. That's OK in your code, but the parameters are pushed to the stack from right to left. That's something your code doesn't do!

> ```
> push esi
> push arr_length
> call print_arr
> ```

The above does not push from right to left for `void print_arr(arr_addr,arr_len)`.

```
push arr_length
push esi
call print_arr
```

---

In the *enter_elem* proc you are interrogating the `EAX` register even before you let *ReadDec* give it a value. Bring `call ReadDec` to the *top* label.

```
top:
    call ReadDec
    cmp  eax, 0
    je   next
    mov  [esi], eax
    add  esi, type arr1
    inc  ebx
    cmp  ebx, 40
    jb   top
next:
```

---

Your *sort_arr* proc tries to do a BubbleSort. Problem is that you only have a single loop there. And even that loop runs for too long! eg. With 40 elements this loop must not run more then 39 times.
Thereafter you need to repeat the process several times but each time with a loop count that is 1 less (because the smallest value will have bubbled to the end of the array, so need no longer be concerned)

---

> ```
> push edx
> push ebx
> call swap
> ```

Given that the *swap* proc expects two pointers (`void swap(x_addr,y_addr)`), the above code from the *compare_and_swap* proc where `EDX` and `EBX` hold array values, will not work.

---

> ```
> mov ebx, [ebp + 8]
> mov edx, [ebp + 12]
> mov [esi], edx
> mov [edi], ebx
> ```

The *swap* proc is cutting corners here! What's the point of having two nice pointers *x_addr* and *y_addr*, if you're simply going to use `ESI` and `EDI` registers deus-ex-machina style? i.e The *swap* proc is not supposed to know what `ESI` and `EDI` contain.

```
; void swap(x_addr,y_addr)
swap proc
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    mov  ecx, [ebp + 8]
    mov  edx, [ebp + 12]
    mov  eax, [ecx]
    mov  ebp, [edx]
    mov  [edx], eax
    mov  [ecx], ebp
    pop  ebp
    ret  8
swap endp
```

Should you decide to use this new *swap* proc, then don't forget to preserve any registers that its caller(s) might be depending on!

---

Except for the call to *enter_elem* where `sub esp, 4` is used to return a result via the stack, the three other instances of `sub esp, 4` are redundant code.